# Android using Azure Mobile Services Delete Null Exception

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services, azure-storage

I am trying to delete a blob and container from my azure mobile services storage and I keep getting an exception from the calls. My upload, geturi, download, getcontainers, etc. all work but neither delete blob or delete container work. I keep getting an exception. For the delete container I get:

```
    Process: com.w9jds.myglassshare, PID: 504
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.w9jds.myglassshare.Classes.StorageService$2.onCompleted(StorageService.java:117)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTableBase.delete(MobileServiceTableBase.java:218)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceJsonTable.delete(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:1)
        at com.w9jds.myglassshare.Classes.StorageService.deleteContainer(StorageService.java:110)
        at com.w9jds.myglassshare.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:116)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18423)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and for the delete blob I get:

```
01-01 23:00:47.561    1457-1457/com.w9jds.myglassshare E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.w9jds.myglassshare, PID: 1457
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=blob.delete flg=0x10 } in com.w9jds.myglassshare.MainActivity$3@41f34b50
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.w9jds.myglassshare.Classes.StorageService$4.onCompleted(StorageService.java:198)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTableBase.delete(MobileServiceTableBase.java:218)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceJsonTable.delete(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:1)
        at com.w9jds.myglassshare.Classes.StorageService.deleteBlob(StorageService.java:191)
        at com.w9jds.myglassshare.MainActivity$3.onReceive(MainActivity.java:187)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code for the two calls are as follows:

DeleteContainer:

```
    public void deleteContainer(String containerName)
    {
        //Create the json Object we'll send over and fill it with the required
        //id property - otherwise we'll get kicked back
        JsonObject container = new JsonObject();
        container.addProperty("id", 0);
        //Create parameters to pass in the container details.  We do this with params
        //because it would be stripped out if we put it on the container object
        List<Pair<String,String>> parameters = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
        parameters.add(new Pair<String, String>("containerName", containerName));
        mTableContainers.delete(container, parameters, new TableDeleteCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
            {
                if (exception != null)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, exception.getCause().getMessage());
                    return;
                }

                //Refetch containers from the server
                //Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                //broadcast.setAction("blob.deleted");
                //mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcast);

                getContainers();
            }
        });
    }
```

DeleteBlob:

```
    public void deleteBlob(final String containerName, String blobName)
    {
        //Create the json Object we'll send over and fill it with the required
        //id property - otherwise we'll get kicked back
        JsonObject blob = new JsonObject();
        blob.addProperty("id", 0);
        //Create parameters to pass in the blob details.  We do this with params
        //because it would be stripped out if we put it on the blob object
        List<Pair<String,String>> parameters = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
        parameters.add(new Pair<String, String>("containerName", containerName));
        parameters.add(new Pair<String, String>("blobName", blobName));

        mTableBlobs.delete(blob, parameters, new TableDeleteCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
            {
                if (exception != null)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, exception.getCause().getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                //Refetch the blobs from the server
                //getBlobsForContainer(containerName);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is `mTableContainer` or `mTableBlobs` defined?

Comment: private MobileServiceJsonTable mTableContainers;
        private MobileServiceJsonTable mTableBlobs;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception happens in the `onCompleted` method, and the only way I can see of a null pointer exception happening is if the `exception.getCause()` call returns null. Try rewriting your methods as follows:

```
public void onCompleted(Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
{
    if (exception != null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, exception.getMessage();
        Throwable t = e.getCause();
        while (t != null)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "  Cause: " + t.getMessage());
            t = t.getCause();
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: OMG! That worked but now I am getting "The entity has an invalid numeric value on id property." I don't understand though because it is the same as in the other calls that work.

Comment: You're trying to delete an item with id `0` - That's an invalid id (the server will never have that), so the SDK is saving you some time (and an HTTP call) telling you that it will fail right away. If you have a custom script on the delete operation on your table where you ignore the item id passed to it, then just use a value other than `0` (i.e., `1`) and it should work.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much! I have been banging my head against a wall on this for days.